# How can I unit test a class with __enter__ / __exit__ methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing, with-statement, python-unittest

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to find a way to test whether the `with` keyword is working correctly in my object.

In this case, my object has an `__enter__` method which creates a temporary directory and `__exit__` method which is supposed to destroy it. (It also has a `do_stuff` method that I only included to test writing to the temporary directory.)

I'm not entirely sure how to approach testing this. I've checked out the `unittest` module, and even written some tests for basic methods before, but I am not sure what the best way is in this case... or if this even makes sense. Anyway, here is my code for the object:

```
import shutil
import tempfile
import os
import glob

class MyObj(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir='.')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        shutil.rmtree(self.tmpdir)

    def do_stuff(self):
        new = os.path.join(self.tmpdir, 'new_file.txt')
        with open(new, 'w') as nf:
            nf.write('testing')
        print(glob.glob(self.tmpdir + '/*'))

myobj = MyObj()
with myobj as x:
    x.do_stuff()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? How to unittest? Can you show the attempts you've made at using the `unittest` module so far? It should be pretty straight forward to write tests for the behavior you've shown, though you want to put the test code in your test case, rather than as a method in the actual class. On the other hand, if you're just asking how to create a temporary directory as a context manager, just use the existing `tempfile.TempDirectory` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test that the `MyObj` works with `with` statement, and it create/delete temporary directory, use the `with` statement in the test method:

```
import unittest


class TestMyObj(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myobj_with_statement__should_create_delete_temp_directory(self):
        with MyObj() as obj:
            # Directory is created
            self.assertTrue(os.path.isdir(obj.tmpdir))
        # Directory is gone
        self.assertFalse(os.path.isdir(obj.tmpdir))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! I wasn't quite getting it because I think I was just thinking about this the wrong way. =)